# How do you pass user input to a system command?

Tags: vimscript, external-command, user-input

I'm trying to write an `autocmd` to make a commit to a git repository. Here is some non-functional code that should illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
let g: CommMsg = ''

augroup misc
  autocmd!
  autocmd nmap <buffer> gc :call GetCommMsg()<CR>!git commit -m '=CommMsg'<CR>
augroup END

function! GetCommMsg()
  let curline = getline('.')
  call inputsave()
  let name = input('Enter message: ')
  call inputrestore()
  let CommMsg = call setline(',', curline . ' ' . name)
endfunction
```

The intention here is to use the `GetCommMsg()` function to get the message from the user, set a global variable to this value and then pass it to the `git commit` command as the message argument.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is what you're aiming for?

```
nnoremap gc :execute '!git commit -m "'.input('Enter message: ').'"'<cr>
```

The only parts of your script that would do anything useful is the first line and the `nmap` line.  The rest of it would either do nothing or not run at all.

Since you're starting to learn VimL, here's a tip: Test simple ideas in the command line.  Every line in a VimL script is something that you can type verbatim in the command line.  You would've seen that the `'=CommMsg'` part of your script would end up being your commit message.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally deleted the `autocmd` from my sample script. Fixed. Your suggestion did not work. Thanks for your input, though. I did get this to work. I'll post in answer.

Comment: It does work.  I just forgot to add `<cr>` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to work pretty well:

```
augroup misc
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter * nmap <buffer> gc :call GetCommMsg()<CR>
augroup END

function! GetCommMsg()
  let curline = getline('.')
  call inputsave()
  let msg = input('Enter commit message: ')
  call inputrestore()
  call system("git commit -m '" . msg . "'")
endfunction
```

Not sure if there are any downsides to doing it this way or not.

Comment: I think it's probably better to just map to vim-fugitive's `:Gcommit` e.g. `nnoremap <Leader>gc :Gcommit<CR>`